# Content type title field not available in manage display

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I have two customized content types, both having a title field. Yet this field does not appear in the Manage Display panel. Moreover, they are not displayed when the content is displayed.

Is this normal? How can I access those title fields? How can I have them displayed?

Comment: It is an odd quirk of Drupal CMS that on the manage display screen you are not able to manage the display of the title; I often want to have an image display first, but the only way to do this is to change the display on the template level.

Answer (score 1):

It is not normal 
but may be the theme you use does not display page title or you hide it with css
anyway you can go to node.tpl and write echo $node->title to check that